# If a batsman is retiries hurt then who will face the next ball?

Tags: cricket

If a batsman is retiries hurt then who will face the next ball ???  Answer me

Answer (score 0):

Next batsman will face the next ball if retiries hurt batsman in the strike. Otherwise, other batsmen will face the next ball. The rules are almost equal to rules dismissal.

Comment: Even if it is the non-striker who retires hurt?

Comment: @PhilipKendall Updated the answer